# Как добавить класс блоку-потомку при ховере на родительский блок

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при ховере на блоке 1 добавить класс на вложенный блок 2.
Хочу добавить класс popup_visible к блоку popup при ховере на блок select в коде ниже, чтобы popup появлялся при наведении.

Это компонент select из библиотеки bem-components. 
Пробовал сделать без js - не получается.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.select');
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
const btn = document.querySelector('.button');

console.log(btn);

select.onmouseenter = function() {
  popup.classList.add('popup_visible');
};

select.onmouseleave = function() {
  popup.classList.remove('popup_visible');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://yastatic.net/bem-components/latest/desktop/bem-components.js+bemhtml.js"></script>
<link href="https://yastatic.net/bem-components/latest/desktop/bem-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="select select_mode_radio select_theme_islands select_size_m i-bem" data-bem='{"select":{"name":"select2"}}'><input class="select__control" type="hidden" name="select2" value="2" autocomplete="off"><button class="button button_size_m button_theme_islands select__button button__control i-bem" data-bem='{"button":{}}' role="listbox" aria-owns="uniq14953563398041 uniq14953563398042 uniq14953563398043"
        aria-labelledby="uniq14953563398044" type="button"><span class="button__text" id="uniq14953563398044">RU</span><span class="icon select__tick"></span></button>
    <div class="popup popup_target_anchor popup_theme_islands popup_autoclosable i-bem"
        data-bem='{"popup":{"directions":["bottom-left","bottom-right","top-left","top-right"]}}' aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="menu menu_size_m menu_theme_islands menu_mode_radio select__menu menu__control i-bem" data-bem='{"menu":{}}'>
            <div class="menu__item menu__item_theme_islands i-bem" data-bem='{"menu__item":{"val":1}}' role="option" id="uniq14953563398041" aria-checked="false">RU</div>
            <div class="menu__item menu__item_checked menu__item_theme_islands i-bem" data-bem='{"menu__item":{"val":2}}' role="option" id="uniq14953563398042" aria-checked="true">UA</div>
            <div class="menu__item menu__item_theme_islands i-bem" data-bem='{"menu__item":{"val":3}}' role="option" id="uniq14953563398043" aria-checked="false">EN</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, так?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('popup_visible ');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).removeClass('popup_visible ');
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.popup_visible {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://yastatic.net/bem-components/latest/desktop/bem-components.js+bemhtml.js"></script>
<link href="https://yastatic.net/bem-components/latest/desktop/bem-components.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="select select_mode_radio select_theme_islands select_size_m i-bem" data-bem='{"select":{"name":"select2"}}'><input class="select__control" type="hidden" name="select2" value="2" autocomplete="off"><button class="button button_size_m button_theme_islands select__button button__control i-bem" data-bem='{"button":{}}' role="listbox" aria-owns="uniq14953563398041 uniq14953563398042 uniq14953563398043"
    aria-labelledby="uniq14953563398044" type="button"><span class="button__text" id="uniq14953563398044">RU</span><span class="icon select__tick"></span></button>
  <div class="popup popup_target_anchor popup_theme_islands popup_autoclosable i-bem" data-bem='{"popup":{"directions":["bottom-left","bottom-right","top-left","top-right"]}}' aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="menu menu_size_m menu_theme_islands menu_mode_radio select__menu menu__control i-bem" data-bem='{"menu":{}}'>
      <div class="menu__item menu__item_theme_islands i-bem" data-bem='{"menu__item":{"val":1}}' role="option" id="uniq14953563398041" aria-checked="false">RU</div>
      <div class="menu__item menu__item_checked menu__item_theme_islands i-bem" data-bem='{"menu__item":{"val":2}}' role="option" id="uniq14953563398042" aria-checked="true">UA</div>
      <div class="menu__item menu__item_theme_islands i-bem" data-bem='{"menu__item":{"val":3}}' role="option" id="uniq14953563398043" aria-checked="false">EN</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Или просто на css

```css
.select:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://yastatic.net/bem-components/latest/desktop/bem-components.js+bemhtml.js"></script>
<link href="https://yastatic.net/bem-components/latest/desktop/bem-components.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="select select_mode_radio select_theme_islands select_size_m i-bem" data-bem='{"select":{"name":"select2"}}'><input class="select__control" type="hidden" name="select2" value="2" autocomplete="off"><button class="button button_size_m button_theme_islands select__button button__control i-bem" data-bem='{"button":{}}' role="listbox" aria-owns="uniq14953563398041 uniq14953563398042 uniq14953563398043"
    aria-labelledby="uniq14953563398044" type="button"><span class="button__text" id="uniq14953563398044">RU</span><span class="icon select__tick"></span></button>
  <div class="popup popup_target_anchor popup_theme_islands popup_autoclosable i-bem" data-bem='{"popup":{"directions":["bottom-left","bottom-right","top-left","top-right"]}}' aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="menu menu_size_m menu_theme_islands menu_mode_radio select__menu menu__control i-bem" data-bem='{"menu":{}}'>
      <div class="menu__item menu__item_theme_islands i-bem" data-bem='{"menu__item":{"val":1}}' role="option" id="uniq14953563398041" aria-checked="false">RU</div>
      <div class="menu__item menu__item_checked menu__item_theme_islands i-bem" data-bem='{"menu__item":{"val":2}}' role="option" id="uniq14953563398042" aria-checked="true">UA</div>
      <div class="menu__item menu__item_theme_islands i-bem" data-bem='{"menu__item":{"val":3}}' role="option" id="uniq14953563398043" aria-checked="false">EN</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю. Не совсем то. Но ваш кода навел меня на мысль. Я добавил js код в пример, который наполовину рабочий. Если просто навести на селект, то ничего не происходит пока не нажать один раз на этот блок. После этого эффект ховера при наведении срабатывает, но когда я выбираю нужный элемент из списка, он теперь не закрывается и не добавляется в поле выбора. Теперь думаю как это можно исправить, оставив первоначальную функциональность?